# How to using Azure Board to trigger a API call or script

Tags: amazon-s3, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-boards

Is there a way I can set up a API call triggering in Azure Board? Lets say one item is "Request approval for creating S3 buckets in AWS", I want to trigger S3 creating API or script when this item's status changed from doing to done.  My end goal is automating tasks like S3 buckets creation, VPC creation, shutdown/start VMs etc in my organization.

Comment: Hi @Bilash Amantay, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: hi @VitoLiu, Eventually I solved this issue with Power Automate. But I'm not sure if this is the best approach.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably wanting to create a [Webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/webhooks?view=azure-devops).

> Webhooks provide a way to send a JSON representation of an event to
> any service. All that is required is a public endpoint (HTTP or
> HTTPS).

You would setup to trigger on work item updated.  You would like need to code on your receiver to interpret the update.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A. If you want to trigger the API via work item state update, you need own website to receive message from VSTS web hook and send request to run the API call or script, and create webhook in the Azure DevOps.
Develop your own website with below functions:

1. Check the current state of the work item updated. You can get a work item information by [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#get-a-work-item), and the check the value for System.State.
2. According to the value of System.State, to trigger related API or script.

B.
Login Power Automate and create a custom workflow. You can refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/) for more details.